# Find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I need to find the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}$,

But I don't really know how. I tried to manipulate integrals and derivetives but it's not helped me. Can you pleae help me to find the sum?

Comment: Do you know the sum of a geometric series?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes

Comment: Okay, then look a little closer to see that a very small modification gives you a geometric series (times a constant).

Comment: @DanielFischer Are you talking about
$\frac{1}{2} \sum \frac{x^n}{2^n}$ ?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: @user1798362, is $\frac{x}{2}<1$?

Comment: @freak_warrior No because $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$

Comment: $|\frac x2| < 1$ is needed more precisely. Outside this interval it will never converge (try adding the first few terms to convince yourself)

Comment: @user88595 I don't have to find convergence , I have to find the sum (even if it's infinity)

Comment: well if my statement isn't satisfied, it will diverge to $+\infty$ for $x\ge2$ and will not have a limit when $x\le2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n
\end{equation}
This is the geometric series, and is convergent for $|x|/2<1$. To calculate the sum you can see here:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html